# JavaFX - Why is my FileChooser giving me access to the origin Stage?

Tags: events, button, javafx, javafx-8, filechooser

When i click on the button, a FileChooser is opened. However, i can for example close the Original Stage while the FileChooser is still opened, or i still can click and switch the actual window. Check the code below

> My questions are :
>  **1- How can i make the FileChooser Closes when i close the main window ? 
>  2- How can i make the main window not clickable when the FileChooser is opened ?**

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setTitle("Main Stage");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);
        stage.show();
        Button button = new Button();
        AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(ap);
        ap.getChildren().addAll(button);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
                Stage stage2=new Stage();
                stage2.initOwner(stage);
                stage2.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage2);  
           }
       });  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenDialog-javafx.stage.Window-)

> If the owner window for the file dialog is set, input to all windows
>   in the dialog's owner chain is blocked while the file dialog is being
>   shown.

However, you are setting the owner window to a window that is not on the screen, so I think there is no "owner chain" in that case, and the file chooser is effectively not modal.

Why not just do

```
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage); 
       }
   });
```

so that you make the owner window of the file chooser the actual window?