# How can i make JavaFX filechooser alwaysonTop of window?

Tags: javafx, filechooser

How can i make JavaFX filechooser is always on top?

In my application some other dialogs call filechooser and that dialog is set as alwaysonTop, so the filechooser dialog is located behind that dialog.
How can i make the filechooser dialog is alwaysonTop of the window?

I made filechooser like this code.

```
    public static File getSaveFileFX(final String suffix, String title) {
        File[] selectedFile = {null};
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        fc.setTitle(title);
        String root = "*" + suffix;
        String fileFormat = suffix + " files";
        fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter(fileFormat, root));
        fc.setInitialDirectory(new File(getRecentDirectoryPath()));

        PlatformImpl.runAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                selectedFile[0] = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
                if(selectedFile[0] != null && !title.equals("Sava To .CSV file")) {
                    //filtering with title
                    mPreferences.put(RECENT_FILE_PATH, selectedFile[0].getAbsolutePath());
                    mPreferences.put(RECENT_DIRECTORY_PATH, selectedFile[0].getParent());
                }
            }
        });

        if(selectedFile[0] != null && !selectedFile[0].getName().endsWith(suffix)) {
            return new File(selectedFile[0].getAbsolutePath()+"."+suffix);
        }else {
            return selectedFile[0];
        }
    }
```

and the other dialog is set as

```
dialog.alwaysOnTop(true);
```

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519518/javafx-why-is-my-filechooser-giving-me-access-to-the-origin-stage) helps.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set main dialog alwaysOnTop(false);
And the dialog of FileChooser alwaysOnTop(true);

Check this sample, its work.

```
    public void initializationDialog(Stage stage) {
    stage.resizableProperty().setValue(false);
    stage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    stage.toBack();
    openFile();
}

public File openFile(String descriptionOfFile, String extensionOfFile) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    Stage stage2 = new Stage();
    stage2.initOwner(stage);
    stage2.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    stage2.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(descriptionOfFile, extensionOfFile);
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
    return fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage2);
}
```